# Question was locked and put on hold, but the banners only show 'on hold' and migration

Tags: support, closed-questions

Came across this question:

- [Enforcing single docent copy in iOS [on hold]](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114081/enforcing-single-document-copy-in-ios)

It's on hold and locked, according to timeline, and I can't comment/edit…

[image]

[image][image]

Yet the banners below the post only shows the migration and the 'on hold' state, with no mention of the lock:

[image]

Is this [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)? I've tagged this as [support](/questions/tagged/support) instead of [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) because I'm not sure yet.

*If so, there seems to be a further problem, since the 'on hold' banner says 'please edit the question' which can't happen because it's locked…*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've cleared the lock. Thanks for spotting the anomaly.

Comment: Does that mean that this is a bug? What exactly happened here — should there have been a 'locked' banner as well as the 'on hold' banner?

Comment: It's not clear if the lock came from the sending site or was a glitch. We get so few migrations into the site, that it's a rare occurrence when a moderator closes a question soon after migration and then community locks the post.

Comment: I know I didn't intend for it to be locked; just put on hold. But given that the OP doesn't have an account here, I'm not hopeful that it will be edited into something useful.

Comment: Just noticed this question on Meta.SO: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147766/what-is-the-reason-for-locking-a-question-migrated-from-another-site-that-is-the Seems the answer is an answer to this too…